# hyperref and cross-referencing

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

When you are using the `hyperref` package, it creates nice, clickable links within the PDF output when you use cross references (`\ref{chap:label}`). But, when I refer to "Section 1", only the "1" is clickable. Is there away to add arbitrary, or semi-arbitrary text to one of these references?

Comment: What would you want to do?  I'm not following with the "add text" part...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides `\hyperref[<link>]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{mysection}
See \hyperref[mysection]{Section~\ref*{mysection}}.
\end{document}
```

To avoid a hyperlink within a hyperlink, it also provides `\ref*`. For less arbitrary but still automated text additions to cross references, it provides `\autoref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
%\providecommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{mysection}
See \hyperref[mysection]{Section~\ref*{mysection}} or \autoref{mysection}.
\end{document}
```

You need to set `\<counter>autorefname` for each of the `<counter>`s you would reference.